# compare csv data and another tables' data in Django

Tags: python, pandas

I have to compare csv data and database table and upload new data upon comparison in Django project. Can you please give me some ideas how to do i?. I was told that by using pandas I can compare and automatically insert the unmatched data as a new data in a column of a table but I couldn't find how to do it.

I have csv file of book and table genre in database. In csv file there is a column genre that consists multiple values. So now I want all the genre name of the csv file as a data in genre table.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Provide example of each DataFrame